# How to save states of multiple dynamically generated checkboxes in a list view? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have an Activity that looks like this - the length of the list view is dynamic and can change; 
[image]

Now, I have declared and initialized checkboxes based on the length of the array. 
I need to save the states of these boxes when the user clicks on "Save". How do I achieve this?  I wrote the following code, but I get no input, i.e. even though the checkboxes are initialized, I don't think the activity knows which checkbox declaration is for which checkbox on the activity. Please help - thanks!

```
cbs = new CheckBox[length];
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        cbs[i] = new CheckBox(ThisActivity.this);
    }
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DoOnBtnClick(v);
            }
        });
    }
    public void DoOnBtnClick (View v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++){
            if(cbs[i].isChecked()){
                selectedCheckboxes.add(toInt(cbs[i].getTag()));
                Log.e("GET TAG",Integer.toString(toInt(cbs[i].getTag())));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to preserve the checkbox state data when user kills the app or activity closed....?

Comment: Hi, yes I want to. Thanks... please help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are creating the `CheckBox` dynamically? Use a model class to store the state of `CheckBox`. Use `Sharedpreference` to save your model class data on app exit.

Comment: I am a novice. Please help me understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sharedPreferences to store and retrieve checkbox state data

Initialize variables first:

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now in your onCreate() after all checkbox are initialized use setOnCheckedChangeListener

Now you can load data from sharedpreferences using this:

```
public void Load_checklist() {
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for(int i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++){
        if (shared.getString(Integer.toString(i), "").equals("1")) {
            cbs[i].setChecked(true);
        }else{
            cbs[i].setChecked(false);
            }
    }
}
```

finally your onCreate method should look like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
      int array_length=jArray.length(); //checkbox size
      //layout where you want to dynamically add checkboxes
      LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyout);
      Load_checklist();
      for(int c=0; c<jArray.length();c++){
        CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);
        chk.setId(c++);
        chk.setText("Click to add values");
        chk.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           String s="x"+buttonView.getId();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch(buttonView.getId()){

              case 1: // do something on 1st checkbox
                    if (isChecked) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(Integer.toString(c), "1");
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(Integer.toString(c), "0");
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                    break;

              case 2: //do something on 2nd  checkbox
                   break;

            //And SO ON for all checkboes
        }  
       }
      });
        linearLayout.addView(chk);
      }
   }
```

N.B: If SetId(Int) is not working then you can use setTag(int) instead.

Comment: @Zac1 see my edited answer , i remove the editor variable declaration on top

Comment: Hi, thanks. I did these, but the onCheckedChanged method never gets called. I put a log in there, and checked the **checkbox** but that loop never gets entered. Also, can you please help me understand how to call _Load_Checlist()_?

Comment: It appears that when I select a few, more checkboxes in the list are automatically getting selected...I don't understand.

Comment: you should call your load_checklist() function only once at onCreate() after  initializing your UI components. i am updating the code...

Comment: Just to summarize: 1) The checked state is not saved when I go to a previous activity and come back, and 2) When I check one box, multiple boxes in the list are automatically selected - don't know why. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If a `CheckBox`'s Tag should represent its index in the list, you should set that tag when you are instantiating them.

```
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
    cbs[i] = new CheckBox(ThisActivity.this);
    cbs[i].setTag(i);
}
```

I would not recommend this approach if you expect to have a variable amount of checkboxes due to the performance implications. Instead, consider using a `RecyclerView` with a backing list of model objects representing the state of your checkboxes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: I already have a lot of code depending on my list view. How easy is it to convert to RecyclerView? I couldn't find any tutorial on it.

Comment: Also, how do I save the states of all checkboxes when the user exits the application?

Comment: Update: For some reason, the [link](if(cbs[i].isChecked()){) loop never gets entered on button click. Why is that?! @sean-amos